# Prove that $f=f(x,y)$ is constant on the lines parallel to the line $y=-x$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f$ be a function of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y)$ for all $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, I need to show that $f$ is constant on any line parallel to the line $y=-x$.

Using the mean value property for a differentiable function of two variables, I got that $$f(x, y)-f(y, x)=(x-y) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \left( x', y' \right)+(y-x) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \left( x', y' \right)=0,$$for some point $(x',y')$ on the segment joining $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$.

i.e, $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ for all $(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2$ ($f$ is symmetric about the plane $x=y$). Now, I feel it can be easy to deduce the desired result using the symmetry of $f$ and the given condition  $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y),$$ for all $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. But I couldn't connect it, thanks in advance for any sort of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lines parallel to the line $y = -x$ can be parameterized as $x \mapsto (x, c-x)$ for some constant $c \in \Bbb R$. So you need to show that the functions
$$
 g_c(x) = f(x, c-x)
$$
are constant, and that follows from the chain rule and the given condition:
$$
 g_c'(x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, c-x) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, c-x) = 0
$$

Or, using a mean value argument: If $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ lie on the same parallel line to $y=-x$ then $x_1+y_1 = x_2 + y_2$, or $x_2 - x_1 = -(y_2 - y_1)$. It follows that for some point $(x', y')$ on the segment joining these points:
$$
 f(x_2, y_2) - f(x_1, y_1) = (x_2 - x_1) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}f(x', y') + (y_2 - y_2) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} f(x', y') = 0 \, .
$$

Comment: How simple and beautiful it was....

Comment: @Riaz: You are welcome. I have added an alternative argument, which is a bit more in the spirit of your attempted proof.